# Redirect HTTP requests to a captive portal

Tags: apache, http

I'm looking for a simple system for redirecting incoming HTTP requests into a captive portal.

I'm currently routing HTTP traffic through Linux iptables, but I'm not sure how to redirect a user into the captive portal (while keeping the URL from the original request for later use).

Is there a simple way to redirect HTTTP requests so it will be rewritten like this:

> **Original request: http://example.com**
>
> **Rewrite it to: http://myportaldemo.com?url=http://example.com**

Is it possible to apply this rule using Apache, Ngnix or any other recommended tool?